# Consequences of Custom HTML Tags in AngularJS Directives

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say I wrote a custom `gravatar` directive in AngularJS that is bound to an `email` property on the scope. The directive would replace this HTML …

```
<gravatar email="user.email" />
```

by a common `img` tag whose `src` attribute is set to the correct Gravatar url:

```
<img src="http://gravatar.com/avatar/..." />
```

My question might be a little broad or even naïve, but "how bad" is it to initially have the `<gravatar />` tag in my page's HTML? Are there any "real-world" consequences besides not passing W3C validation?

Comment: Beside W3C (who cares) you have to [deal with IE](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie). Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Why does it have to be a different tag?

Comment: @ExplosionPills It doesn't, I might as well restrict the directive to an attribute. That wouldn't illustrate my question adequately, though.

Comment: I added a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589864/angularjs-directives-as-custom-html-tags-isnt-this-dangerous-and-may-conflic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The W3C says

> Authors must not use elements, attributes, or attribute values for purposes other than their appropriate intended semantic purpose, as doing so prevents software from correctly processing the page.

and

> Authors must not use elements, attributes, or attribute values that are not permitted by this specification or [other applicable specifications](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#other-applicable-specifications), as doing so makes it significantly harder for the language to be extended in the future.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#elements

Custom elements/attributes have no semantic value and should be avoided for these reasons.

There probably won't be any *direct* consequences that you will even notice.  After all, Angular itself uses the non-confirming `ng` attributes (although they do support with the `data-` prefix as well).

The only possible problem you may face is if the element you introduce that is currently a custom element becomes part of the spec and has different behavior than what you were expecting before, but I think that is highly unlikely.  Even so, I would avoid using anything custom if I could.

[Eventually you will be able to register your own custom elements](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/spec/custom/index.html), but from what I can tell no browser supports this spec yet.

Answer (score 4):

While the initial source of the page body (before angular processes an ng-app element) may not adhere to the W3C standards, if you use "replace: true" in directives, custom elements are replaced by a template HTML, which can be valid. So, in this case, you can think about an angular element as just a placeholder that is replaced with the terminal HTML output.