# How to use AngularJS without custom HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I’m trying to use [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)’s inline datepicker, but it works with a custom tag:

```
<datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate"></datepicker>
```

My template processor doesn’t support custom tags, is there a way to have this working with a standard tag, e.g. something like `<div ng-something="datepicker"></div>`?

There have been discussions on how/why AngularJS uses custom tags [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17503102/735926) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18665303/735926), and AngularJS has some [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) on how make IE8 accept custom tags using JS, but my problem is at the HTML generation step, i.e. it’s not a problem with the browser.

Note that I can’t change my template processor, and this question is larger than that since you have to use standard tags if you want to have a W3C-compliant HTML. AngularJS lets you use standard attributes (by prepending `data-`), but I can’t find a way to use standard tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something along these lines:

`<div data-datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate"></div>`

EDIT: It should work, as the datepicker directive from ui-bootstrap (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js) seems to have `restrict` attribute set to `'EA'`, which means, that you can use it by `E`lement or `A`ttribute. So I think you're good to go with my example provided above.